# ActivClient/CAC: How to get the container AID?

Tags: smartcard, cac

I'm trying to work with ActivClient BSI against CAC cards (PKI).

How can I get the AID of the containers?

For now, I'm using the AID I saw in the ActivClient UI. Are these values constant?

If yes, where can I find a list of all these constants?

If no, how can I programaticly get these values?

Thanks,

Mattan

Answer (score 1):

The container OIDs of the current CAC card are specified in NIST 800-73-3 part 2, available on the nist.gov site. These values are constant.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better ask ActivClient vendor about these details.

I don't know what a "container AID" is in this context, but an AID is usually an "Application Identifier" and it should be constant for a given card, as host-side software is expected to know this value.